Querying a BinData field by $bitAllSet with an offset and size limit in MongoDB
Assume I have a BinData field of arbitrary length that stores n-byte items. The offset of each item is known before the query and all items are n bytes. I want to test an item at offset X with bitmask Y. It is important to mention that I don't want to do a  search, just a bitmask test, for the offset is known.
Currently, I'm reading the whole field and testing on my server side.
Is there a way to do it on MongoDB side?

Does your MongoDB server allow the use of "$function".

@rickhg12hs yes, but I would prefer not to use functions for this type of task.

Yes it is possible.  However, since an index will not help, every query using bit mask check will be a collection scan.
To test individual bits, you first need to create a pair of masks, one to match the bits you want to be 1 and another the match the bits you want to be 0
For example, I created a collection containing some 22-byte binary objects:
[
{"i":0,"b":{"$binary":{"base64":"P40M+wuXLpQSSrk=","subType":"00"}}},
{"i":1,"b":{"$binary":{"base64":"2AQ/oJEM8Nm3TdU=","subType":"00"}}},
{"i":2,"b":{"$binary":{"base64":"R1qgtnJpT1efm9E=","subType":"00"}}},
{"i":3,"b":{"$binary":{"base64":"yMCw8yq42iZxSe4=","subType":"00"}}},
{"i":4,"b":{"$binary":{"base64":"1FSUZUvlKwFMea0=","subType":"00"}}},
{"i":5,"b":{"$binary":{"base64":"qml1+0cd8E+3hLQ=","subType":"00"}}},
{"i":6,"b":{"$binary":{"base64":"wToGlD672/zqP04=","subType":"00"}}},
{"i":7,"b":{"$binary":{"base64":"uM4igB9AvbNH5XQ=","subType":"00"}}},
{"i":8,"b":{"$binary":{"base64":"Hb9RKX47DnRCCc4=","subType":"00"}}},
{"i":9,"b":{"$binary":{"base64":"/vdvzBeBYYo2okk=","subType":"00"}}}
]

To find documents where the 9-12 bits (3rd hexadecimal digit) are 5, i.e. 0101, the mask for bits that are 1 would be "0050", depending on the client, that could be one of:
new Binary(Buffer.from("0050", "hex"))
new HexData(0,"0050")
new BinData(0,"AFA=")
the mask for bits that are 0 would be "00A0"
new Binary(Buffer.from("00A0","hex"))
new HexData(0,"00A0")
new BinData(0,"AKA=")
Then querying the collection containing the above sample documents could look like:
db.collection.find({b:{
                   $bitsAllSet: new Binary(Buffer.from("0050", "hex")),
                   $bitsAllClear: new Binary(Buffer.from("00A0","hex"))
                  }})

The Playground displays things in base64 so it is not immediately obvious that the query worked there.
I ran this in my local mongodb instance, outputting the binary as hex, and we can clearly see the 3rd hex digit is indeed 5 for each match:
> db.collection.find({b:{$bitsAllSet:HexData(0,"0050"),$bitsAllClear:HexData(0,"00A0")}}).map(d=>{return {i:d.i,b:d.b.buffer.toString("hex")}})
[
  { i: 2, b: '475aa0b672694f579f9bd1' },
  { i: 4, b: 'd45494654be52b014c79ad' }
]

The mongod server does not provide helper functions for building binary values or shifting the bits to the right, but most programming languages will, so building a mask Y that is offset by X bits should be a matter of using the shift and invert operators.
